# Google Drive unlimited space for .edu domain

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

I have received unlimited Google Drive space from my educational institute with .edu domain.

**Q1:** How long will I be able to access this unlimited storage (life time or for a specific period)?

**Q2:** If the organisation shuts down for some reason then in that case also will I be able to access this storage (domain also shuts down by organisation)?

Answer (score 1):

1. For as long as you have an account with that educational institution.  Typically this will be only as long as you are working or studying there.
2. No.   If the domain owner shuts down the domain, it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask to your .edu domain administrator the organization policies that apply to your organization / account.

NOTE: Nowadays there are two specific G Suite editions for education centers but they could opt to any of the G Suite editions.

There are a broad range options to "shut down" a domain. If the organization disable accounts most of the related data / files will be kept. To delete an organization account the organization first should delete all the user accounts and in that case the files and data of each account will be permanently deleted.

Related

- [Allow graduating students to transfer their data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6364687?hl=en)
- [Suspend a user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33312?hl=en)
- [Cancel your G Suite subscription](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646?hl=en)